# how to get value from a loop while using different button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need the value from a loop witch is $row->value, then when I click on button_click(href) a DIV popup will show and ask for another value that is idnumber.
At the popup a submit button will direct to next_page.php

I want both value from loop $row->value and at popup value=idnumber send to next_page.php

```
<div id="show_popup"(hide/show popup)>
 <form action="next_page.php" method="GET or POST">
  <input name="idnumber" type="text" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="button">
 </form>
</div>

<?php 
 foreach($foo as $row){
 echo "
 <tr>
   <td>".$row->value."</td>
   <td><a class='button' href='#' onlick='(popup DIV)'>button_click</a></td>
 </tr>";
 }
?>
```

Is this possible?

```
$(function() {
   function launch() {
   $('#show_popup').lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() { $('#add-new-popup').find('input:first').focus()}});}
   $('.button').click(function(e) {
   $("#show_popup").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
$("#show_popup").find("input:first").focus();}});e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Comment: yes it is possible using `AJAX`.

Comment: place `</form>` after `foreach`

Comment: lets say Im using ajax.

Comment: Can we know what kind of popup you are using? Is it any jquery plugin or your own?

Comment: I edited the the post. Added the function use to show the popup.

Comment: What value does $row->value need to have when the pop-up appears?

Comment: Nothing.
the popup is just a verification form if the IDnumber is valid then proceed to next page but I need both of the value IDnumber and $row->value in the next_page.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your click handler:

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    var rowValue = $(this).closest('td').prev().text();
    $("#show_popup").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
        $("#show_popup").find("input:first").focus();
        $("#show_popup form").prepend($('<input type="hidden" name="rowName" value="' + rowValue + '" />'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move your $row->value to that IDnumber textbox, then try this.

Change your button code,

```
<td><a class='button' href='#' onlick='(popup DIV)' value='".$row->value."'>button_click</a></td>
```

In your Jquery button click function, add this line.

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
   $("#show_popup").lightbox_me({centered: true, onLoad: function() {
   $("input[name='idnumber']").val(($(this).attr('value')));
   $("#show_popup").find("input:first").focus();}});e.preventDefault();
});
```

This will give you what i mentioned in the top

Comment: sorry but I'm not good at javascript.
how should get the value of $row->value at jquery function?

Comment: you are not getting in Jquery function. you just create an attribute "value" in your button anchor link and add this $("input[name='idnumber']").val(($(this).attr('value'))); line code in your button click function